# How to add a Runbook action to a Metric rule (classic) using Json Template Azure?

Tags: json, azure, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template, azure-runbook

Im having an issue about how to add a Runbook action to my metric alert, there is a lot of dosumentation about sending email to owner, but none of them tells about an action Runbook.

This is my template to create a Metric alert:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "AlertName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "VirtualMachineId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "MetricName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Operator": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Threshold": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Aggregation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "WindowSize": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "microsoft.insights/alertRules",
      "name": "[parameters('AlertName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('AlertName')]",
        "description": "[parameters('Description')]",
        "isEnabled": "true",
        "windowSize": "[parameters('WindowSize')]",
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',parameters('VirtualMachineId'))]",
            "metricName": "[parameters('MetricName')]"
          },
          "operator": "[parameters('Operator')]",
          "threshold": "[parameters('Threshold')]",
          "windowSize": "[parameters('WindowSize')]",
          "timeAggregation": "[parameters('Aggregation')]"
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "odata.type": "RuleAction"
            //Runbook....
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no documentation about adding a RuleAction and im stuck at this point after creating a virtual machine with a Json Template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your Runbook in the portal, go to `Webhooks` -> `Add Webhook`, create a new webhook and copy the `URL`. For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#creating-a-webhook).

2.In your template, add the sample below to the `actions`, and specify the `webhookUrl` with your webhook URL , refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-alerts-using-template#resource-manager-template-for-a-resource-with-a-classic-metric-alert).

```
"actions": [
                {
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                    "sendToServiceOwners": "[variables('sendToServiceOwners')]",
                    "customEmails": "[variables('customEmails')]"
                },
                {
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
                    "serviceUri": "[variables('webhookUrl')]",
                    "properties": {}
                }
            ]
```

Create the alert and check it in the portal, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: yes I know that too but I am looking for an option to assign a runbook actioninstead of using a Webhook.

Comment: @Sharaz Just curious why not use a webhook?

Comment: I have been told to not to use it, the programme must use a powershell action.